# device location is always null

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have gone through many posts on SO regarding this issue:
Tried everything in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1513485/840520),
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8524934/840520) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8526771/840520) Nothing works. Everytime location is null. On device and on emulator :(. My GPS is on,internet is on and my manifest has following permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

I use following code to get the location i.e the longitude and latitude of the device...however in every case I get `location` as `null`

```
public void find_Location() {
        Log.d("Find Location", "in find_location");

        String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(location_context);

        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        for (String provider : providers) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
                    new LocationListener() {
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

                        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        }

                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        }

                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                int status, Bundle extras) {
                        }
                    });
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location == null) {
                Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Location Not found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                        "LAT..." + latitude + "\nLONG..." + longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // addr=ConvertPointToLocation(latitude,longitude);
                // String temp_c=SendToUrl(addr);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't downvote this...coz I have gone through sooo many of the posts and still unable to get `location`.

Comment: Not sure about this...can you try restarting your phone's wi-fi ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could I be so stupid..My bad....In settings **Use Wireless networks** was  not selected!....That cause all the problems !!
Now I am able to get a location.

It took me 16 hrs to get to this...my productivity going down for sure! :(

Comment: Still this thing doesn't work on my emulator though. Works on device.

Comment: in emulator you need to send the lat and longitude manually by DDMS device control

Comment: @VipinSahu: Thanks Vipin.I had already done that. As I mentioned the **Use Wireless networks** was unchecked in my device and on Emulator.Once I checked it, everything started working.

Comment: Still this thing doesn't work on my emulator though. Works on device.... what does it mean

Comment: Works on device meaning and does not work on Emulator means AFAIK, `Location info` is displayed only on device. It does not work on Emulator.

Comment: i added already that DDMS perspective is used to manually send the location update ..... as your emulator has no gps and network .. it rather uses your pc . so pleas pass the location vie ddms then you will get location on emulator too...... and also emulator location never changes as it stay connected with your pc ...........

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time before the position is determined, and it can change over time. It's probably just not available yet when you check it.

When a position fix becomes available, you will be notified in onLocationChanged.